# Derivative of hyperbolic decline equation

Tags: derivatives

I have the following equation:

$$
 y = q_0\left(1+\frac{bx}{a}\right)^{-\dfrac 1b}$$

where $q_0$, $a$ and $b$ are constants.  I am trying to get the first derivative with respect to $x$.

Here's what I have so far.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-q_0}{a}x^\frac{-b-1}{b}
$$

But I don't think that this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had a good thinking (at least for the general method of derivation), however, it seems to me that you simplified the term a bit quickly:

$$
1+\frac{b x}{a}
$$

It can't be deleted as you did. So the result would be more like:
$$
-\frac{q_0 \left(\frac{b x}{a}+1\right)^{-\frac{b+1}{b}}}{a}
$$

Sincerely,

La Jargille